# Is it possible to infer a generic class type from a non-constructor method parameter in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

#### A- Constructor Method Case

When I want to infer the generic class type **from a constructor method** parameter:

```
interface ObjectAsMap { [key: string]: boolean }

interface MyClass<T extends ObjectAsMap> {
  data: T

  constructor(data: T): MyClass<T>
}

class MyClass<T extends ObjectAsMap> {
  constructor(data: T) {
    this.data = data
  }
}

const a = new MyClass('Wrong parameter type')
const b = new MyClass({
  first: true,
  second: false,
})

console.log(b.data.first)
console.log(b.data.wrongProperty)
```

**As expected**, I get [2 errors](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ObjectAsMap%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20boolean%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20ObjectAsMap%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20T%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(data%3A%20T)%3A%20MyClass%3CT%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20ObjectAsMap%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(data%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.data%20%3D%20data%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20new%20MyClass('Wrong%20parameter%20type')%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20new%20MyClass(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20first%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20second%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(b.data.first)%0D%0Aconsole.log(b.data.wrongProperty)%0D%0A):

- `new MyClass('Wrong parameter type')` triggers `Argument of type '"Wrong parameter type"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObjectAsMap'.`
- `b.data.wrongProperty` triggers `Property 'wrongProperty' does not exist on type '{ first: true; second: false; }'.`

---

#### B- Non-Constructor Method Case

Now, if I want to trigger exactly the same expected behavior **from a non-constructor method**:

```
interface ObjectAsMap { [key: string]: boolean }

interface MyClass<T extends ObjectAsMap> {
  data: T

  declare(data: T): MyClass<T>
}

class MyClass<T extends ObjectAsMap> {
  public data: T

  public declare(data: T) {
    this.data = data

    return this
  }
}

const myClassInstance = new MyClass()

const a = myClassInstance.declare('Wrong parameter type')
const b = myClassInstance.declare({
  first: true,
  second: false,
})

console.log(b.data.first)
console.log(b.data.wrongProperty)
```

**I only get [the first error](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ObjectAsMap%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20boolean%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20ObjectAsMap%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20T%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20declare(data%3A%20T)%3A%20MyClass%3CT%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20ObjectAsMap%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20data%3A%20T%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20declare(data%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.data%20%3D%20data%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myClassInstance%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20myClassInstance.declare('Wrong%20parameter%20type')%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20myClassInstance.declare(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20first%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20second%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(b.data.first)%0D%0Aconsole.log(b.data.wrongProperty)%0D%0A):**

- `myClassInstance.declare('Wrong parameter type')` triggers `Argument of type '"Wrong parameter type"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObjectAsMap'.`.

The `b.data.wrongProperty` should also trigger an error since this property does not exist within `b#data`. When I hover the mouse above `b.data`, it tells me `(property) MyClass<ObjectAsMap>.data: ObjectAsMap` instead of `(property) MyClass<{ first: true; second: false; }>.data: { first: true; second: false; }`.

---

#### Question

Is there a way to infer the parameter type in Case B like I do it in Case A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an extra type parameter to capture the actual type of `data` in the call

```
interface ObjectAsMap { [key: string]: boolean }

interface MyClass<T extends ObjectAsMap> {
    data: T

    declar<U extends T>(data: U): MyClass<U>
}

class MyClass<T extends ObjectAsMap> {
    public data: T

    public declare<U extends T>(data: U): MyClass<U> {
        this.data = data

        return this as any
    }
}

const myClassInstance = new MyClass()

const a = myClassInstance.declare('Wrong parameter type')
const b = myClassInstance.declare({
    first: true,
    second: false,
})

console.log(b.data.first)
console.log(b.data.wrongProperty)
```

Comment: It still doesn't catch the parameter type from what I just tested. You can double-check on the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) _(the code sharing link is too long to insert it in a comment)_.

Comment: @EdouardHienrichs not usre what you mean .. I get an error on `b.data.wrongProperty`. It will not affect the type of the original `myClassInstance`

Comment: Sorry @titian-cernicova-dragomir I indeed forgot the second return declaration as `MyClass<U>`. It works, thank you very much !